# Only one of two listbox is being populated on the button click

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I'm trying to populate two listboxes with two different lists I'm reading in from a database. Here is my code:

```
private void StartSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\TriHard.accdb";
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT Time.AthleteID, Athlete.AthleteName, Time.EventTime, Event.EventDistance FROM Event INNER JOIN (Athlete INNER JOIN [Time] ON Athlete.[AthleteID] = Time.[AthleteID]) ON Event.[EventID] = Time.[EventID];";
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, Connection);
        Command.Connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();


        List<PaceCalculator> Distancelist = new List<PaceCalculator>();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            pace = new PaceCalculator();
            pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
            Distancelist.Add(pace);
        }


        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Distance";
        listBox1.DataSource = Distancelist;

        List<PaceCalculator> TimeList = new List<PaceCalculator>();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            pace = new PaceCalculator();
            pace.Time = (string)Reader["EventTime"];
            TimeList.Add(pace);
        }

        listBox2.DisplayMember = "Time";
        listBox2.DataSource = TimeList;






    }
```

When I press the button, listBox1 is populated, but listBox2 is not. How can I solve this so both boxes are populated next to each other?

Comment: I think you are missing a line. In that code, the second list box will be reading off of nothing (since the previous one already read everything).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET how would I go about changing that?

Comment: Put the pace.Time and TimeList in the first while loop.  It's that, or you create another Reader with a different Command object.  You need to put your disposable objects in using {} blocks to dispose of them.  Right now, you aren't closing your database connections, etc.

Comment: Above the second while loop, you need some `ExecuteReader` command. Probably not off of the initial command object, since you said the two lists were different.

Comment: I think @LarsTech is right about moving lines into 1st loop. Don't forget to create new PaceCalculator as well, so move all 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OleDbDataReader provides a way to read data from your underlying database in a forward mode only. So, when you reach the end of your loop, you cannot restart it hoping to read again from the init of your data.
Thus is simply a matter to read both the Distance and Time values from your datasource and add them to a single PaceCalculator object instance and add it to your lists. All of this inside a single loop.

When you exit the loop just set the DataSource of your listboxes to the two different lists and set the different `DisplayMember` properties

```
    List<PaceCalculator> TimeList = new List<PaceCalculator>();
    List<PaceCalculator> Distancelist = new List<PaceCalculator>();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        pace = new PaceCalculator();
        pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
        pace.Time = (string)Reader["EventTime"];
        Distancelist.Add(pace);
        TimeList.Add(pace);
    }

    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Distance";
    listBox1.DataSource = Distancelist;
    listBox2.DisplayMember = "Time";
    listBox2.DataSource = TimeList;
```